# Only get filename and extension of listing, not whole path

Tags: listings, captions, parsing

I am trying to add the file name as caption. I was able to do this setting

```
caption=\lstname
```

but this shows the full path. I am now trying to get the name of the file and extension to show only. I was trying to use the `\filename@parser`, but no luck.

This is how the code look like:

```
\ifdefined\docdefined
\else
%   \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt, openright]{report}
    \input{include_start}
    \begin{document}
\fi

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

% START DOCUMENT
\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter

\lstset{language=C, 
numbers=left, 
frame=single, 
commentstyle=\color{dkgreen}, 
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily}, 
keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
%identifierstyle=\color{blue}, 
stringstyle=\color{mauve},
captionpos=t,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=3,
caption={\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@base\text{.}\protect\filename@ext},
}

\begin{frame}
% LIST FILES HERE:


\lstinputlisting{C:/Users/x/Project/trunk/User/Drivers/ADC.h}

\lstinputlisting{C:/Users/x/Project/trunk/User/Drivers/ADC.c}


\end{frame}
\end{appendices}

% END DOCUMENT
\ifdefined\docdefined
\else
    \input{include_end}
    \end{document}
\fi
```

I am pretty sure the syntax is wrong here:

```
   caption={\filename@parse{\lstname}\filename@base}
```

I am trying to parse `\lstname` and get the base.

Comment: can you not just use `\lstinputlisting{ADC.h}` (and then arrange that C:/Users/x/Project/trunk/User/Drivers/ is in TEXINPUTS ?

Comment: It says it can not find the files. "! Package Listings Error: File `ADC(.h)' not found."

Comment: Please (always) make your code fragments a complete document showing all packages used, so people can test their answers. An unprocessable fragment is less helpful.

Comment: I don't see how listings could fail to find the file if it's in your texinputs path.

Comment: Complete code now shown in question.

Comment: Thanks for the code (just a minute late for me as I'd already amended the colours to make the code in my answer work:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `\protect` to protect both `\filename@parse` and `\filename@base` inside the moving argument of `caption`:

```
caption={\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@area}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I will update question. I used to line: caption={\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@base\text{.}\protect\filename@ext} to get filename.extension.

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid a complicated set of macros as the value of `\caption`; by defining a separate command, you can easily add adjustments. Here I fixed the behavior of `listings` that changes hyphens into `\textendash` and added `\texttt` around the file name.

Note, though, that you won't be able to compile correctly the list of listings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\getlstname}{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{\lstname}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

% START DOCUMENT

\lstset{
  language=C, 
  numbers=left, 
  frame=single, 
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen}, 
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily}, 
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
  %identifierstyle=\color{blue}, 
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  captionpos=t,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  caption=\getlstname,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{/Users/enrico2013/primaria2014-02-04.tex}

\end{document}
```

I used one of my LaTeX files for the example.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

is produced from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,listings}

\lstset{language=C, 
numbers=left, 
frame=single, 
commentstyle=\color{green}, 
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily}, 
keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
%identifierstyle=\color{blue}, 
stringstyle=\color{red},
captionpos=t,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=3,
caption={\lstname},
}

\begin{document}


\lstinputlisting{io.h}

\end{document}
```

You only need do give the filename not the full path so long as you use a command such as

```
TEXINPUTS=/usr/include: pdflatex list22
```

or equivalent in whatever command shell you use (the above is bash syntax)

Comment: If I understand correctly the TEXTINPUTS is to be written in a cmd line and not as part of the .tex document?

Comment: @Phataas yes or a texmf.cnf config file, or in your system environment settings. Basically listings uses the same mechanism to find foo.h as \documentclass uses to find article.cls You don't specify a full path to article.cls normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the searching path, and then in the caption you will have only the filename.

This works for me:

```
\newcommand{\cfile}[2][]{
    \lstinputlisting[style=customc, caption={\texttt{\detokenize{#2}}},#1]{#2}
}

\lstset{inputpath=some/funny/path}

...

\cfile{file_name.c}
```

The file is located in `some/funny/path/file_name.c`. `customc` is a custom style, you can delete it. The `\texttt` and the `\detokenize` are for the special characters in the file name and the first optional parameter of the `\newcommand` is for adding features when use the command, like for instance `\cfile[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{file_name.c}`.