# Extract filename from path

Tags: listings, parsing

For labelling purposes I want to print the filename with extension given a full file path (in `\tt` font)

Based on Egreg's answer in [Only get filename and extension of listing, not whole path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174553/67086) I cooked up this command, but I doesn't work with underscores and all my attempts to modify it accordingly failed so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    Works: \filename{path/to/file.txt} % prints: file.txt

    Fails: \filename{path/to/file_2.txt} % should print: file_2.txt
\end{document}
```

I also tried building a similar command the `xstring` package, but that didn't work out for me either. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stringify `\filename@base` before using it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\filename{path/to/file.txt} % prints: file.txt

\filename{path/to/file_2.txt} % should print: file_2.txt

\end{document}
```

[image]