# Macro to change the extension of filename

Tags: macros, graphics, parsing

I would like to have a macro to change the extension of a file name. For example, my macro needs to take an argument like `Figures/Fig.xxx` and return me `Figures/Fig0.yyy`.

I found a solution in [Extract filename from path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325046/extract-filename-from-path). It is as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\changefilename}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
    \def\textendash{-}%
    \filename@parse{#1}%
    \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
    \texttt{\filename@area\filename@base0.yyy}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

But, when I use the output of this macro in `\includegraphics{}`, I get an error.

Comment: You can't put your macro `\changefilename` _inside_ `\includegraphics` because it has typesetting commands, thus it doesn't expand to “plain text”. Try this definition: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\changefilename}[2][\relax]{%
\begingroup
\def\textendash{-}%
\filename@parse{#2}%
\edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
\ifx\relax#1%
  \texttt{\filename@area\filename@base0.yyy}%
\else
  \xdef#1{\filename@area\filename@base0.yyy}%
\fi
\endgroup
}` then you can do `\changefilename[\foo]{Figures/Fig.xxx} \includegraphics{\foo}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The `expl3` parser would work there ...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Your suggestion is good, can you make it as `answer`? It will help others...