# Evalution of new version command / Code review

Tags: macros, code-review

*I'm still newbie latex user, so I need help from advanced users to figure out in macros restrictions and their pitfalls*

### Prerequisites:

I need to extract filename from its path, and I found this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325052/272637. But it does not support passing command as parameter (a.e. `\filename{\mycomm{param}}`).

What happen if I call `\filename{\mycomm{param}}`?
Assume, `\mycomm{param}` defined as

```tex
% NormalTeXSyntaxON
\def\setcase#1 {\expandafter\def\csname col:#1\endcsname}
\def\mycomm#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname col:#1\endcsname\relax \coldefault 
                \else \csname col:#1\endcsname\fi}

\def\coldefault {example/path.l}

% NormalTeXSyntaxOff
```

And \filename defined as in solution:

```tex
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

- Actual result: `filename{\mycomm{param}}` prints `example/path.l`
- Expected result: `path.l`

### Proposed update:

I added support passing command as parameter, and tried to make this feature cross-platform. Also I added support for optional first parameter (i.e I can call `\filname[\bfseries]{path}` to make path bold).

New definition:

```tex
\newcommand{\runtimeFsep}{/}
\newcommand{\updateRuntimeFsep}{\IfSubStr{\currfileabsdir}{/}{}{\renewcommand{\runtimeFsep}{\backslash}}}

\updateRuntimeFsep

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
    \def\textendash{-}%
    \filename@parse{#2}%
    \IfSubStr{\filename@base}{\runtimeFsep}{\filename@parse{\filename@base}}{}%
    \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
    #1{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

New solution has disadvantages:

1. It has more dependencies:

```tex
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{currfile}
```

2. It require pass '-recorder' option to LaTeX compiler because of currfile not work without it.

---

Minimal Working Example for old command:

```tex
\documentclass{letter}

% NormalTeXSyntaxON
\def\setcase#1 {\expandafter\def\csname col:#1\endcsname}
\def\mycomm#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname col:#1\endcsname\relax \coldefault 
                \else \csname col:#1\endcsname\fi}

\def\coldefault {code/taskN.cpp}
% NormalTeXSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \filename{\mycomm{a}}
\end{document}
```

---

Minimal Working Example for new version of command:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{currfile}

% NormalTeXSyntaxON
\def\setcase#1 {\expandafter\def\csname col:#1\endcsname}
\def\mycomm#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname col:#1\endcsname\relax \coldefault 
                \else \csname col:#1\endcsname\fi}

\def\coldefault {code/taskN.cpp}

% NormalTeXSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\runtimeFsep}{/}
\newcommand{\updateRuntimeFsep}{\IfSubStr{\currfileabsdir}{/}{}{\renewcommand{\runtimeFsep}{\backslash}}}

\updateRuntimeFsep

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
    \def\textendash{-}%
    \filename@parse{#2}%
    \IfSubStr{\filename@base}{\runtimeFsep}{\filename@parse{\filename@base}}{}%
    \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
    #1{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\filename{\mycomm{a}}     
\end{document}
```

---

Is this good update? New version of this command has any pitfalls?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please don't post fragments of code. Gather the code into a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so make things easier for the people willing to help.

Comment: So your code already works you just look for some code review?

Comment: `\edef\filename@base{\detokenize` will  break any non ascii characters in  the filename if you are using latex or pdflatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That part was originally copied from egreg's linked answer (although it looks reasonable either way)

Comment: @user202729 a detokenized name would work for file access commands, but if you want to print it, you need  the inputenc active characters

Comment: @user202729, Code already works, I just want code review and tips from community)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, How to fix this? I may assume, just remove \edef and suppres \filename@base output?

Comment: well it's not clear what the intention is, generally I'd avoid xstring functions as thy are not expadable and these days the forma has equivalet funcionality already loaded without a package needed in the expl3 string functions. Personally I would probably just use `\filenamè@parse` and in the rare occasions need the full path, just arrange to pass in the current directory on the command line. As I note above it also depends if you are using the filename to print  or if you are using it to pass to external filesystem commands.